# Change Chrome Inspector's Default Browser Dimensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-testing

I am trying to figure out how to edit the default Chrome Default Dimensions Tab inside Inspector. (See Video). Currently the tabs cater for mobile devices with width 320px, 375px, 425px, tablets 768px, laptops 1024px, 1440px and 4k devices from 2560px. Since my laptop is 1920px I have to constantly keep clicking the Dimensions dropdown to select my laptop from the list, and when I click on any of the default tabs, it resets the dropdown and I have to repeat the steps to view my laptop dimension again. If I could simply add my laptop dimension to the taps, it would save me a lot of time. Is this possible?

[image]